# Is there a way to "unflatten" a table in SQL into multiple normalized tables? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data generated by an SQL XML query that uses one cross apply and one outer apply create a table of the following form:

```
COL 1   | COL 2 |   COL 3
abe     |   dog |   ball
abe     |   dog |   stick
abe     |   cat |   yarn
ben     |   cow |   NULL
ben     |   dog |   water
ben     |   dog |   stick
```

In this example, col 1 is people, col 2 is their pets, and col 3 is a list of things their pets like (the pets may not like anything). In reality, columns 1,2 and 3 are each represented by multiple columns.

I want to "unflatten" this data into 3 tables, person, pet and pet_interests. In doing this I would also like to create a many to one relationship from pet to person and a many to one relationship from pet_interests to pet.

I am unable to find a way to do this without iterating through the data manually with C#, but I feel like there must be a easier way. I was hoping someone would be able to help me with the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your output more clearly? Are you trying to turn this into three tables? One each for Person, Pet and PetInterests? You are going to need to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Yes. "I want to "unflatten" this data into 3 tables, person, pet and pet_interests. In doing this I would also like to create a many to one relationship from pet to person and a many to one relationship from pet_interests to pet."

Comment: OK. so what have you tried? This process is known as normalization.

Comment: I am aware that what I am trying to do is normalization, but normally this refers to database design. I am unable to find anything on the actual process of normalizing and "unnormalized" table like this. Therefore I have tried nothing, as nothing in my SQL knowledge would work for this, nor would anything I was able to find in an hour or so of internet research. Hence I came here.

Comment: See Gordon's answer. That is the process you will need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I will show the approach.  First, create the reference tables:

```
select identity(1, 1) as personId, col1 as name
into persons
from t
group by name;
```

Repeat for the rest of the tables.

Then use the reference tables for your 1-1 tables:

```
select identity(1, 1) as personPetId, p.personId, pe.petId
into personPets
from t join
     persons p
     on t.col1 = p.name join
     pets pe
     on t.col2 = pe.species
group by col1, col2;
```

Repeat as necessary.